# setting up drawable.invalidate to continuously draw on canvas

Tags: android, callback, drawable, invalidation

i am trying to incrementally change the alpha value of an OvalShape()..
for this i need to call the invalidate , so that it keeps calling itself and render itself with increased alpha value..

but the setup is wrong, as i dont have much idea about this..

```
public class xml_anim_testing_sub_class extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int width = 300;
    int height = 50;
    int my_alpha = 255,add_to_my_alpha = 0;

    public xml_anim_testing_sub_class(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        x++;
        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setAlpha(my_alpha += add_to_my_alpha );
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        if (my_alpha == 0)
            add_to_my_alpha  = 1;
        if (my_alpha == 255)
            add_to_my_alpha  = -1;
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        mDrawable.invalidateSelf();
    }
}
```

ok, i found out the solution, `invalidate()`, but then what is the difference between `invalidate` and `postInvalidate`? cos both are working..

also, what is the use of?

```
mDrawable.invalidateSelf()(cb);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling `mDrawable.invalidateSelf()`, call `postInvalidate()` (for the view itself). This will schedule another drawing pass after the current one finishes.

Also, you don't need to allocate a new ShapeDrawable each time through onDraw. Just assign it in the constructor once. This will cut down on garbage generation.

Comment: i cant believe, but i tried a new thing, and it worked, i typed invalidate at the end of onDraw.. n it worked.. :) 

but not sure if its efficient.. n i placed the "new ShapeDrawable" in Constructor.. :) thanks.. a lot..

so what is the difference between invalidateand postInvalidate??? cos both are working..

also, what is the use of??

mDrawable.invalidateSelf()(cb);

Comment: @Mahesh - `postInvalidate()` will give the framework a chance to process any other events that may have queued up during drawing. I suggested that instead of `invalidate()` because that's what some of the sample code uses. `Drawable.invalidateSelf()` will call the view's `invalidateDrawable()` method, which will invalidate only the current bounds of the drawable. If you aren't moving the drawable around, this will have the same effect as calling `invalidate(mDrawable.getBounds())`. If you are moving `mDrawable`, this might miss some of the area that needs drawing.

Comment: @Mahesh The up triangle to the left of the answer is the "like button". :) Also, if an answer solves your problem, you can mark it as the solution by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

```
invalidate()
```

Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future.

This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

The post invalidate will queue a invalidate task for the UI thread (Main looper) to execute in a FIFO fashion.